# Couchdb error, bad request, reason, invalid_json

Tags: php, json, curl, couchdb

Learning Couchdb using this guide: http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/tour.html

and I have got to the bit for uploading files. I can do it using the browser but not from the command line, unfortunately this is my first experience with JSON, so knowing what I have done wrong is very tricky, could someone tell me what I might be doing wrong.

So I have checked and double checked the "-id" and the "-rev" and they are both correct with the doc I am on in that I can add other fields with text in successfully.
and I am in the same directory that the image file is in and I have created a little jpg image and called it thing.jpg

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
curl -vX PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/albums/b8afcee69b7f2d7267bda14dc2002ba3/ thing.jpg?rev=1-08e6f33452dc44b0aa0df15c2cda1a98 --data-binary @thing.jpg -H "Content-Type: image/jpg
```

Here is the response:

```
> PUT /albums/b8afcee69b7f2d7267bda14dc2002ba3/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5984
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: image/jpg
> Content-Length: 39844
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: CouchDB/1.4.0 (Erlang OTP/17)
< Date: Wed, 22 Jun 2016 09:46:05 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 48
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 
* Closing connection 0
* Rebuilt URL to: thing.jpg/?rev=1-08e6f33452dc44b0aa0df15c2cda1a98
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Could not resolve host: thing.jpg
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: thing.jpg
```

Beyond that, the syntax looks identical to the tutorial, but I am getting this error, as mentioned before, I am able to add other fields but not upload via the curl command. I tried with a different doc to upload an image via the browser UI and that went fine.

Please point me in the right direction for correcting this, or at least let me know what I am doing wrong so I can research this better.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a blank too much in the URL part of your cURL command.

Additionally a quotation mark is missing at the end.

The command should be:

```
curl -vX PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/albums/b8afcee69b7f2d7267bda14dc2002ba3/thing.jpg?rev=1-08e6f33452dc44b0aa0df15c2cda1a98 --data-binary @thing.jpg -H "Content-Type: image/jpg"
```